# how to extract the remaining memory from free using awk?

Tags: bash, memory, awk, free-command

I need to extract the available memory from the output `free` and I thought I would use awk and came up with something like `free | awk '{print $4}'`.
Which gives me an output like:

```
$ free | awk '{print $4}'
shared
365296
1273812
3931364
```

mind, the title **shared** isn't the title of these numbers, the numbers are from free (`/usr/bin/free` has no title in the first column, thus the numbers for free appear in the 4th column where the title reported is from the 5th). However, having this, how do I only return the second line? I'm not interested in the rest for now.

Answer (score 8):

```
free | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

NR, is the ROW/Line number

Comment: +1 but add `;exit` after `$4` since the OP only wants the 2nd line, not the 2nd and subsequent lines.

Comment: shoudn't `;exit` be redundant in this case ? The above command will only print the second line; Note `NR==2`.

Comment: It'll produce the correct output, it's just inefficient since it'll continue parsing the rest of the input after the 2nd line. I don't know how many lines of output `free` can produce so that may or may not be a concern.

Comment: Most linux system shows about 4 lines when `free` is typed, so not losing much here.

Comment: OK, I'm on Solaris and cygwin and don't have a command named `free` either place so I'd no idea what it outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out myself, it can be accomplished using:

```
$ free | awk '{print $4}'| head -2| tail -1
```

Comment: -1 for posting an answer to your own question instead of updating your question with your best attempt at an answer and asking for something better or just deleting your question if you think your answer is the best one for you.